# hibernate duplicate domains while getting data

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, eager-loading

I have two tables where there is a one to many relationship between those tables.
   here is a tables: Category table (Parent table)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name="CATEGORY_NAME")
private String categoryName;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TmCategoryPropertiesMapping
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tmCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<TmCategoryPropertiesMapping> tmCategoryPropertiesMappings;
.............
....... getter and setters
```

and the other entity: category Mapping table (child table)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name="CREATED_BY")
private BigInteger createdBy;

@Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
private Timestamp createdDate;

@Column(name="PROPERTY_ID")
private BigInteger propertyId;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TmCategory
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID")
private TmCategory tmCategory;
```

Here if I get the categories using owner ID I am getting duplicates in my result.
Even though I have only 3 entries in category table but I am getting 10 entities in my result. 
What is the reason for this?
any how can I overcome from this?
The table data is here:
[image: category table data] 
[image: category mapping table data]

The result I get here is
id= 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3

Answer (score 1):

You have made the toMany association EAGER. This means that **every** time a category is loaded, all its mappings are also etrieved. Which means that, instead of retrieving one row per category, N rows are retrieved.

To deduplicate the result list, you simply need

```
select distinct
```

instead of

```
select
```

But I would not make the toMany association eager. If you really need categories with their mappings in some use case, the explicitely fetch them, instead of fetching them every time, even when not needed:

```
select distinct c from Category c
left join fetch c.tmCategoryPropertiesMappings
where ...
```

Comment: Sorry I am not using SQL query here, I am using HQL.

Comment: Err, the queries in my answer ARE hql queries

Comment: oh sorry, i just missed it

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it.
This happens with relationships with tables with eager fetching.
To come out of this problem we need to specify distinct in criteria itself and here is the solution:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Category.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ownerId", BigInteger.valueOf(id)));
    criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        List<Category> categories = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

Note the line

```
            criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

this removes the duplicates from the result set.